# My form doesn't appear anymore

Tags: django, forms

My application was rendering a form but without sending data too other applications . Now I am saving form in order to send  every data to another application when I access to it my form doesn't appear anymore

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from choix.forms import ConfigurationForm
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
def index(request):
    form = ConfigurationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ConfigurationForm(data=request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
           e_mail = request.POST.get('e_mail', '')
           temps = request.POST.get('temps', '')
           temperature = request.POST.get('temperature', '')


           return render(request,'configuration.html')


    return render(request, 'configuration.html', {'form' : form })
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action='configuration.html' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
 <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
 </form>
{% else %}
<p> Pour avoir l'opportunite d'acceder a cette fonctionnalite de notre application , vous devez  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/accounts/login">s'authentifier</a>  tout d'abord 
Si vous n'etes plus un membre ,veuillez <a class="navbar-brand" href="/accounts/register">s'inscrire  </a>  </p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

configuration.html

Comment: Is user authenticated?

Comment: `return redirect(request,'configuration.html')` doesn't make a lot of sense. `render` seems more appropriate. You cannot redirect to a template!

Comment: @ozgur even when I authenticate it renders the button submit only

Comment: @schowobaseggl I corrected it as you said but it is not that the problem